# Triggering ALM test sets (UFT tests) in Jenkins Unix slave

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hp-uft, alm, continuous-delivery

We have a Jenkins Unix slave through which builds are scheduled in different testing environments.

**Objective:**
To schedule a job in Jenkins unix slave to trigger 2 ALM test sets(containing 30 UFT test cases each) in 2 different physical machines.

**Could you please let me know the following:**

i. Is it possible to trigger a job to run ALM test sets(containing UFT scripts) in a Jenkins Unix slave ? 
ii. If yes, then is it possible in Jenkins to know that execution of all 60 scripts has been completed so that entire team can be notified of the results.

**Analysis done from our side:**
We checked with our Jenkins admin to provide a Windows slave but its not possible due to project restrictions. If we schedule a job in Jenkins to run a Windows batch file , it throws an exception as it tries to run the .bat file in Jenkins Unix Slave.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official [UFT PAM - Operating Systems](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/documents/uft/UFT_14.xx_PAM.html#Operating%20systems), it is not Supported - only on Windows Computers. If you are doing Web Testing, then you can try UFT Developer (or formerly LeanFT) that supports Linux Systems.

If it's only WebTesting than on the other side you are better of with some Free Tools, beginning with Selenium, Taiko, Cypress etc